# Why are the differences between Babel French and English?

Tags: babel, babel-french

I just noticed that `\usepackage[french]{babel}` does indent the first paragraph of each section which is not the case in english. So I went to the [manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) to understand the differences, but I found nothing about paragraphs. So then I looked at the locale on GitHub (https://github.com/latex3/babel/tree/master/locale/fr) but again I did not find anything relevant even in the `.dtx`.

How can I *quickly* look at what the option `[french]` does?

Side question: I noticed that french-switzerland exists (but I cannot use it with `\usepackage[french-switzerland]`. How should I call it?

Comment: Probably try with `\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide{french-switzerland}` instead?

Comment: @leandriis Where did you find this information?

Comment: If you look in the log you'll notice that for french bable loads a corresponding `.ldf` file. So the code is in there

Comment: Oh ! So the princess is in another castle... There is another package then:  https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/french/frenchb-doc.pdf...

Comment: Babel-french documentation consists of two pdfs: `frenchb.pdf` and `frenchb-doc.pdf`. The latter is written in French, and ghas more details on customisation.

Comment: As a general rule the (traditional) `babel` localisation modules are distributed as packages separate from core `babel` and have their own documentation. That's where you would be looking for language-specific stuff. Usually the `babel` modules are called `babel-<language>`, e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-german, https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-dutch, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-french. The French localisation module is available as `babel-french`, but its documentation is in `frenchb.pdf` and `frenchb-doc.pdf` (I assume for historical reasons).